# How to prove the equivalence of these two optimization function?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

How can I prove that,
$X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$:
    \begin{align}
  \min_{\beta\in\mathbb{R}^p}\|y-X\beta\|_2^2
\end{align}
is equivalent of the problem,
    \begin{align*}
  \min_{v\in\mathbb{R}^n} \|y-v\|_2^2 \text{ subject to } X^Tv = 0
\end{align*}

What I have attempted so far is by letting $z = X\beta$, the original problem becomes

\begin{align*}
  \min_{\beta\in\mathbb{R}^p}\|y-z\|_2^2 \text{ subject to } z=X\beta
\end{align*}

so we can therefore write the Lagrangian form of our original function as $\|y-z\|_2^2+v^T(X\beta-z)$

By KKT condition,

$$
\nabla L(\beta, z,v)_\beta=X^Tv=0\\
\nabla L(\beta, z,v)_z=-2(y-z)-v=0\\
z=y+\frac{v}{2}$$

I then achieve $$\min_{v}v^T(\frac{v}{4}+y), \text{subject to } X^Tv=0$$

Where wrong is my derivation here?

Comment: Take the derivative w.r.t. $\beta$ instead.

Comment: @LinAlg Now I have $\frac{X(z-y)}{\|y-z\|_2}+X^Tv$ in hand, what should I do next? It seems that I should let $X^Tv=0$ in order to construct the "dual" problem, in which I don't really know if the $v$ I introduced in the first problem is the $v$ in the description of the second problem.

Comment: Where does the first term come from?

Comment: @LinAlg It comes from the $\frac{\partial \|y-z\|_2^2}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial \beta}$

Comment: You should treat $z$ independent from $\beta$. The correct equivalent problem is in my other answer. $X^Tz=0$ is trivial (derivative w.r.t $\beta$). What you currently have shows that $||v||=1$, but only if $z-y \neq 0$.

Comment: @LinAlg Hi, I've updated my description, could you look at my current derivation and tell me where am I wrong? I can neither achieve the result I expect nor the one you provided.

Comment: Your derivation is correct! The reason your dual differs from mine is that you start with the squared norm (instead of the norm).

Comment: @LinAlg Thank you so much! Though the original dual provided is supposed to be right, it seems so weird to me. Could you look at the question I post here? I got some difficuty getting the constraint. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1963265/how-to-derive-the-dual-for-min-cut-problem

Answer (score 1):

In general, those two conditions are not equivalent. Take for instance $n=p$ and $X$ invertible. Then
\begin{align}
  \min_{\beta\in\mathbb{R}^p}\|y-X\beta\|_2=0,
\end{align}
while
\begin{align*}
  \min\{ \|y-v\|_2^2: {v\in\mathbb{R}^n}\text{ subject to } X^Tv = 0\}=\|y\|^2_2.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can we prove that in non-general cases, they are equivalent problems?

Comment: You are right. The correct equivalent problem is $\sup_z \{ -\beta^Tz : ||z|| \leq 1, X^Tz=0 \}$