# How to derive the dual for min-cut problem?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I have a min cut problem formulated below.

\begin{aligned}
  \min_{b\in \mathbb{R}^{|E|}, x\in \mathbb{R}^{|V|}} \quad & \sum_{(i,j)\in E}b_{ij}c_{ij} \\
  \text{subject to} \quad    \quad  &  b_{ij}  \geq x_i - x_j \quad \text{for all} \; (i,j) \in E \\
                        & b \geq 0 \\
                        & x_s - x_t \geq 1 \\
  \end{aligned}

Now I am deriving its dual, I've introduced three slack variables $f,y,w$ that corresponding to three constraints in the primal.

What I have achieved so far. 
\begin{align*}
\max_{f,y,w}\min_{b,x}\left( \sum_{(i,j)\in E}b_{ij}c_{ij}+\sum_{(i,j)\in E}f_{ij}(x_i-x_j-b_{ij})-\sum_{(i,j)\in E}y_{ij}b_{ij}+w(1-x_s+x_t)\right)\\
f,y,w \geq 0\\
\max_{f,y,w}\min_{b,x}\left( w+\sum_{(i,j)\in E}b_{ij}c_{ij}+\sum_{(i,j)\in E}f_{ij}(x_i-x_j-b_{ij})-\sum_{(i,j)\in E}y_{ij}b_{ij}+w(-x_s+x_t)\right)\\
=\max_{f,y,w}\min_{b,x}\left( w+\sum_{(i,j)\in E}b_{ij}\left(c_{ij}-f_{ij}-y_{ij}\right)+\sum_{j:(j,i)\in E}x_jf_{ij}-\sum_{j:(i,j)\in E}x_jf_{ij}+(-x_s+x_t)w\right)\\
=\max_{f,y,w}\min_{b,x}\left( w+\sum_{(i,j)\in E}b_{ij}\left(c_{ij}-f_{ij}-y_{ij}\right)+\sum_{j:(j,i)\in E}x_j(f_{ij}-f_{ji})+(-x_s+x_t)w\right)\\
\end{align*}

However I have some difficulty deriving the constraints, what would that be? I've extract all the dual variables at front.

Comment: @LinAlg b is a vector that each element within is corresponding to an edge in the graph, and $i$, $j$ stands for every adjacent nodes in the graph.

Comment: @LinAlg I think, by adding $b$ into the Lagrangian form has led me force to write $c-f-y=0$. However I got really confused about the last two terms, since $x_i-x_j$, I cannot say whether it is constrained or not, how am I suppose to write the constraint on $f$ and $w$ then?

Comment: To extract $x_i$, use the sets $\{j \; : \; (i,j) \in E\}$ and $\{j \; : \; (j,i) \in E \}$. Also note that E is typically used for edges while A is used for arcs.

Comment: @LinAlg Thank you. I've extracted $x_i$ and updated the description. Can I safely conclude that $f_{ij}$ is now equals to 0 because $x_i$ and $x_j$ is not constraint at all? How about the last term? Since I've add the constraint of $x_s-x_t \geq 1$ into the Lagrangian function, I assume this part is not constraint as well? And would that give us the constraint $w=0$? But that doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: @LinAlg How am I suppose to achieve that? It really confuses me and the final formulation should be a max-flow problem right?

Comment: @LinAlg Thank you so much! I think that is $f_{ij}=f_{ji}$ right? However how do I derive the final term with $w$?

Comment: it is not clear to me if you use edges or arcs; in the last step: what is $i$ in the summation over $j$?

Comment: @LinAlg Sorry for the confusion, these are edges, so each $i,j$ pair means $i$ and $j$ are adjacent.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you derive the dual constraints by finding for which f,y,w the $\min_{b,x}$ is $-\infty$. However, since $x$ is binary, that is far from trivial. Additionally, since the problem is not convex (due to the domain of $x$ and $b$), the duality gap is not 0. For these reasons, the dual of an integer linear program is never derived.

Comment: I am sorry I think I posted a wrong version of the original problem, the version I've updated is a relaxed version of integer linear programming. Thank you for letting me know that the dual of an ILP problem will not be derived!

Comment: @good2know, Did you find a solution?